# Provide Specific Face Colors to trisurf? (MatPlotLib, PY 3.10)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm attempting to find a way to provide different colors to the `trisurf` function, called on a `scatter` plot, in `Python 3.10` using the `MatPlotLib` module.

Let's say I have the following simple plot script:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

X = [1, 3, 2, 4]
Y = [1, 1, 2, 2]
Z = [2, 2, 2, 2]

ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, s = 0)
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlim(0, 5)
ax.set_ylim(0, 3)
ax.set_zlim(1.9, 2.1)

ax.set_xlabel('X Axis')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Axis')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Axis')

plt.show()
```

The script above generates 2 faces on a single plot, as such:

[image]

As far as I understand, one is able to supply either a singular RGB color value to be applied to all generated faces, or a color map.

Here's the result of the script above, with the addition of the `color = [1, 0, 0]` argument to the `plot_trisurf` call:

[image]

Now all the generated faces are painted in the single provided color.

I was wondering, however, whether it was possible to supply a specific color for each generated face, in a single plot? So for instance, in my example, if I wanted for one face to be red (`[1, 0, 0]`), and one to be blue (`[0, 0, 1]`)?

A color argument of `color = [[1, 0, 0], [0 ,0 ,1]]` (where each sub-list of the color list is supposed to be the color of each one of the faces in my example), gives an error of `RGBA sequence should have length 3 or 4`.

As far as colormaps go, I understand that you can generate custom ones.
In my example I could have something akin to:

```
colors = [(1, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1)]
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list(
        "Custom", colors)
sm = mpl.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap = cm)
```

Which would give me the following colormap:

[image]

However, I'm quite unsure of how to reference the color index of the colormap. It doesn't seem like I can provide just a list of indices. This is all the more confusing to me, as [the documentation of the plot_trisurf function](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.plot_trisurf) doesn't provide much detail for the possible forms of the `color` argument. It just states `Color of the surface patches`.

Is it even possible to provide explicit face colors as a list, to the `plot_trisurf`? Is there a different & better way to achieve this?

Thanks for reading my post, and guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `color` argument to `plot_trisurf` is either a *single* Matplotlib's color, or a list of Matplotlib's colors, one for each triangular facet of the tri-surface (hence, `n_triangles` must equal `n_colors`).

If you provide a correct triangulation to `plot_trisurf` you can also (relatively) easily provide a color array, otherwise the situation could be complicated and it's easier to go with the colormap.

If you opt to use a colormap, by default `plot_trisurf` uses the mean *z* value for each triangular facet as an "index" into the colormap.

Comment: Thank you for your reply; How do I provide it with the color array? If I try to provide either one color per face, or one color per vertex in the form of a 2D list, I get an error stating that the "color array should be of length 3 or 4". Does it specifically have to be a 2D numpy array?